# Is this property true for all increasing convex functions $f$ with $f(0)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ is a twice differentiable increasing convex function with $f(0)=0, f'(0)=0$. Fix $x_0>0$. Consider $x\in[0,x_0)$. We all know that $f'(x)<\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}\;\forall\;x\in[0,x_0)$ and $f'(x)$, $\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}$ are both increasing in $x$ for $x\in[0,x_0)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \uparrow x_0}\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}=f'(x_0)$. My question is, does $f'(x)$ also *increase faster* than $\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}$ for $x\in[0,x_0)$?, i.e. is $f''(x)\geq \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}\right)$ for all $x\in[0,x_0)$? Which simplifies to the following for all $x\in[0,x_0)$:

$$
f''(x)(x_0-x)^2+f'(x)(x_0-x)+f(x)-f(x_0) \stackrel{?}{\geq}0
$$

I'm trying to draw pictures of $f'(x)$ and the parameterized increasing function $p(x;x_0)$ defined as $\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}$ for $x \neq x_0$ and $f'(x_0)$ for $x=x_0$, which is $>(<) f$ for $x<(>)x_0$ and $=f'$ for $x=x_0$. Also, this property holds for linear and quadratic functions. Not sure if it holds more generally. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried $f(x) = x^3$? Unless I am mistaken, $f''(x)\geq \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}\right)$ becomes $6x > x_0 + 2x$, and that is not true for small $x$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I verified - this is true. Therefore the claim is not true in general. That's very helpful.